# Electric Field Integral

Tags: electromagnetism

In the example shown below, I need to know how dy(the numerator portion of the integral) gets converted into x sec²θdθ.

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n13fC.png)

[Integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDoO3.png)

Comment: Perhaps $r=x \sec \theta$ and $y=x \tan \theta$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Kevin, thanks for pointing that out